# Capture command output inside zsh function

Tags: function, zsh

I'm trying to write a zsh function to get the path to a python module.

This works:

```
pywhere() {
  python -c "import $1; print $1.__file__"
}
```

However, what I'd really like is the dir path without the filename. This doesn't work:

```
pywhere() {
  dirname $(python -c "import $1; print $1.__file__")
}
```

Note: it works in bash, but not in zsh!

EDIT this is the error:

```
~ % pywhere() {
function →   dirname $(python -c "import $1; print $1.__file__")
function → }
  File "<string>", line 1
    import pywhere() {
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This looks correct, and it works for me. How doesn't it work for you?

Comment: ah - just noticed same on another system works fine. So must be something in my zsh configuration I guess.. ugh!

Comment: The error happens if I use the title function in preexec, from here:
http://dotfiles.org/~_why/.zshrc

I've just commented this out for now. Not sure exactly why this interferes with function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to a broken `preexec`: you aren't quoting the command line properly when you print it for inclusion in the window title.

In the `.zshrc` you posted, which is not the one you used (don't do that! Always copy-paste the exact file contents and commands that you used), I see:

```
a=${(V)1//\%/\%\%}
a=$(print -Pn "%40>...>$a" | tr -d "\n")
print -Pn "\ek$a:$3\e\\"
```

`print -P` causes prompt expansion. You include the command in the argument. You protect the `%` characters in the command by doubling them, but that's not enough. You evidently have the `prompt_subst` option turned on, so `print -P` causes the `$(…)` construct in the command line that defines the function to be executed:

```
python -c "import $1; print $1.__file__"
```

where `$1` is the command line (the function definition: `pywhere { … }`).

Rather than attempt to parse the command line, print it out literally. This'll also correct other mistakes: beyond not taking `prompt_subst` into account, you doubled `%` signs but should have quadrupled them since you perform prompt expansion twice, and you expand `\` sequences twice as well.

```
function title() {
  a=${(q)1} # show control characters as escape sequences
  if [[ $#a -gt 40 ]]; then a=$a[1,37]...; fi
  case $TERM in
  screen)
    print -Pn "\ek"; print -r -- $a; print -Pn ":$3\e\\";;
  xterm*|rxvt)
    print -Pn "\e]2;$2 | "; print -r -- $a; print -Pn ":$3\a";;
  esac
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this:

```
python -c "import os, $1; print os.path.dirname($1.__file__)"
```